# Python for loop through nested dictionary question?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, nested

Trying to loop through a nested dictionary and want to store values into name, age and occupation. Without manually creating those variables within the for loop. Is this even possible? Just trying to create cleaner looking code. Thank you.

```
people = {
    1: {"name": "Simon", "age": 20, "occupation": "Data scientist"},
    2: {"name": "Kate", "age": 30, "occupation": "Software engineer"},
    3: {"name": "George", "age": 22, "occupation": "Manager"},
}

for person in people:
    for name, age, occupation in people[person].values():
        print(name, age, occupation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inner loop is not necessary. You just need to unpack the values object.

```
for person in people.values():
    name, age, occupation = person.values()
    print(name, age, occupation)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```py
people = {
    1: {"name": "Simon", "age": 20, "occupation": "Data scientist"},
    2: {"name": "Kate", "age": 30, "occupation": "Software engineer"},
    3: {"name": "George", "age": 22, "occupation": "Manager"},
}

for index, person in people.items():
    name, age, occupation = person.values()
    print(name, age, occupation)
```

If you want index you can keep it and if you don't you can change it to underline

Comment: Another great answer. Thank you so much for your help and quick response. Much appreciated :)